# Parameterizing 'SELECT IN (...)' queries

Tags: python, mysql

I want to use MySQLdb to create a parameterized query such as:

```
serials = ['0123456', '0123457']
c.execute('''select * from table where key in %s''', (serials,))
```

But what ends up being send to the DBMS is:

```
select * from table where key in ("'0123456'", "'0123457'")
```

Is it possible to create a parameterized query like this? Or do I have to loop myself and build up a result set?

*Note: executemany(...) won't work for this - it'll only return the last result:*

```
>>> c.executemany('''select * from table where key in (%s)''',
        [ (x,) for x in serials ] )
2L
>>> c.fetchall()
((1, '0123457', 'faketestdata'),)
```

---

Final solution adapted from Gareth's clever answer:

```
# Assume check above for case where len(serials) == 0
query = '''select * from table where key in ({0})'''.format(
    ','.join(["%s"] * len(serials)))
c.execute(query, tuple(serials)) # tuple() for case where len == 1
```

Comment: The IN clause can not be parameterized to use a single variable to hold a comma separated list -- this requires dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this, I think:

```
query = 'select * from table where key in (%s)' % ','.join('?' * len(serials))
c.execute(query, serials)
```

Comment: I know I can build the query like that myself, however I'm hoping to rely on the library to do data sanitization for me as 'serials' is coming from an untrusted source.^U Oh wait - I see what you did there. Clever! Lemme try that out.

Comment: If `serials` is really untrusted you might want to check its length before using it like this.